# Is it possible to exclude specific namespace from Kyverno Policy Report

Tags: kyverno

We have a kyverno cluster policy and use it for generating reports. But I want to exclude some specific namespaces from this check.
I used the default exclude method, and I could see it got applied in the cluster policy. But still these namespaces is not getting removed in the policy report.

Some way to exclude some namespace from kyverno policy report.